# Visual C# 2010 Express: show elements of array while debugging?

Tags: debugging, visual-c#-express-2010

Isn't it possible to show all elements of an array or datatable etc. while debugging just by hovering over the elements pointer (like in Visual Studio)? I get some properties or so when I keep the mouse on the variable name but it doesn't show me the actual content! Can I change this or is this a limitation of Visual Express? (I'm using the 2010 version)

Answer (score 0):

You just have to insert a ***breakpoint*** on or before the `array`. Then there's several ways to view the array contents in VS.

Breakpoints:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ktf38f66(v=vs.71).aspx

Debugging tutorial (has screenshots and details on exactly what your asking for):
http://www.dotnetperls.com/debugging

[image]

Another decent tutorial with details of debugging controls:
http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/visual_studio_breakpoints.html

> F11: Step Into - This button is designed to allow the programmer to enter a function or a class allocation without having to set a breakpoint in the code. This is very useful for situations where you have a top level function that calls several other functions and you want to track the program flow going into that particular desired function. What will happen is when you enter a function, the debugger either jumps to another part of the code on the page if it exists in the same module, or loads the pertinent module for you and takes you to the beginning of the entered function. During this time you can continue to step line by line and watch where the program cursor goes to see what is happening in the code. You can of course set up watch variables along the way to monitor the function you stepped into.

Comment: I know how to get the context menu with a breakpoint but I can't find the values of a datatable for example.

Comment: `foreach (DataRow r in dt.Rows)
            {
                DataLink.Get("Select " + TASK_RES + " FROM " + ASS_TBL + " WHERE " + TASK_UID + " = " + r[TASK_UID], ds, "Assignment");
                dt2 = ds.Tables["Assignment"];

                Task t = new Task();

                Project.areas_[0].AddTask(t.CreateTask(r[TASK_UID], r[TASK_OUT_NUM], r[TASK_START], r[TASK_FINISH], r[TASK_DUR], dt2.Rows[0][TASK_RES]));

            }`
that's the part where i want to check the content of dt and dt2. I don't if this will help you (and I'm sry, I don't know how to write code properly in a comment)

Comment: It looks to me that you can insert a ***breakpoint*** on the loop(`foreach` line) and walk the loop using the ***step into*** button to see all the values. But I don't think your gonna see the values in to loop until you walk the loop. ***step into*** allows you to follow each step the code takes as it makes it with each click. It won't make more than 1 step per click.

Comment: I've added some details about ***step into*** above.

Comment: I'm using breakpoint and of course do step by step debugging. I now figured out how to display a datatable: hoover over the variable name, click the triangle next to the magnifying glas and then "DataTable Visualizer". But you can't continue with the visualizer opened. I still haven't found any hint to show the data grid direct in the context menu to be able to continue with the code.

Comment: Are you applying the values directly to the DataTable? or are you binding the DataTable to an Object and applying the data to the Object which updates the DataTable?

Comment: I assume this is what you tried to do? http://davidhayden.com/blog/dave/archive/2005/12/26/2645.aspx